# Тип "WeatherTypes | undefined" не может быть назначен для типа "WeatherTypes". (2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Я использую масив обэктов(data), но не могу его типизировать .

Error: Тип "WeatherTypes[] | undefined" не может быть назначен для типа "WeatherTypes[]".
Тип "undefined" не может быть назначен для типа "WeatherTypes[]".ts(2322)

```
Хуки
  const [name, setName] = React.useState<string | null>("");
  const [city, setCity] = React.useState<string | null>("Киев");
  const [country, setCountry] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<WeatherTypes[]>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=************************=${city}&units=metric&lang=ru&cnt=24`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const data = response.data;
          setData([data.list[0], data.list[7], data.list[15], data.list[23]]);
          setName(data.city.name);
          setCountry(data.city.country);
        }
      });
  }, [city]);
```

```
types.ts

export interface WeatherTypes {
  main?: mainTypes[];
  weather?: weatherTypes[];
  wind?: windTypes[];
  clouds?: cloudsTypes[];
  dt_txt?: string;
}

export type mainTypes = {
  temp?: number;
  humidity?: number;
};
export type weatherTypes = {
  description?: string;
  icon?: string;
};
export type windTypes = {
  speed?: number;
};
export type cloudsTypes = {
  all?: number;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас инициирующее значение undefined (в скобках) а указан тип WeatherTypes[]

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState<WeatherTypes[]>();
```

надо как то так

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState<WeatherTypes[]>([]);
```

Comment: @You Love пометьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог